# Best way to fill list from WS Async in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, listbox, webserver

I have a Panorama control with 8 PanoramaItems, each containing a LongListSelector. Using MVVM the listbox is bound to a ObservableCollection property.

I need to fill each list with data (a lot of data photo , text ..) from a webserver.

How do I do this, the best way, without blocking the UI thread ?

I tried something like this

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => LoadList1());
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => LoadList2());
...
```

Where the Load function looks like this:

```
[EDIT] using Rx  
private IDisposable _disp;
private void LoadList1()
{
      _disp = Observable.FromEvent<PhotoEventArgs>(_webServer, "GetPhotosCompleted")
                        .Select(a => from l in a.EventArgs.Result
                                     where l.Name.Length > 1
                                     group l by l.Name.ToLower()[0] into c
                                             orderby c.Key
                                             select new Group<Photo>(c.Key, c))
                        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                        .Subscribe(a =>
                        {
                             List1Items = new ObservableCollection<Group<Photo>>(a);
                             _disp.Dispose();
                        });

     _webServer.GetPhotosAsync();
}
```

It’s working, but the UI is still frozen a part of the time.

How can I make this perform better ?

I guess the problem is that I uses LongListSelector, so I need to add all the data at once to the List1Items for the LongListSelector to group correct.

EDIT: there is a bug in the Windows Phone Toolkit - Nov 2011 (7.1 SDK) 
coursing the LongListSelector to group wrong !

Answer (score 1):

The part of this that blocks the UI thread is where you set the List1Items to be the entire result set, try breaking that up in multiple insertions, say 5 or 10 at a time. I'm writing this from my phone so it is hard to give you a code example, but it looks like you have the coding part under control and just needed a lille kick in the right direction.

Comment: Adding 5 og more items at the time, will cause the bound LongListSelector to group the data wrong. –

Answer (score 0):

You should consider looking into [Reactive Extensions for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431792%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Your code would end up looking somewhat like this:

```
private void LoadList1()
{
    Observable.FromEvent<PhotoEventArgs>(
        e => new EventHandler(e),
        e => _webServer.GetPhotosCompleted += e,
        e => _webServer.GetPhotosCompleted -= e
    ).Select(e => 
    {
        return 
            from l in e.Result
            where l.Name.Length > 1
            group l by l.Name.ToLower()[0]
            into c
            orderby c.Key
            select new Group<Photo>(c.Key, c);
    })
    .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(result => 
    {
        foreach (var item in result)
            List1Items.Add(item);
    });
}
```

Comment: Will that run the List1Items.Add(item) differently ?
consider what Bendik Nilsen Aune wrote.

Comment: Well, if you override the *entire* ObservableCollection, you'll be forced to update the entire UI. By adding the items, it won't freeze out the UI.

Comment: But I have to call the base.RaisePropertyChanged("List1Items") after the foreach (var item in result) to get the UI to refresh. so won't that be the same as setting the List1Items = result ?

Comment: No, you don't. If List1Items is a observable collection, and you don't change the actual reference (the collection reference itself), it's not necessary to raise it as changed (as the reference haven't changed). You seem to have misunderstood how references and INotifyPropertyChanged works in C#. Go read up :p

Comment: I will do that. you code result i a cross-thread access (FYI).

Comment: Does not! The SubscribeOnDispatcher() runs the result on the current dispatcher.

Comment: Use the ObserveOnDispatcher works insted, but using foreach will cause the bound LongListSelector to group the data wrong

Comment: How can it *possible* group it wrong, when you *already* grouped it? I'm going to go with a "you're doing it wrong". Think you need to play with what you're doing some more, and learn how thing works, before asking questions ;-)

Comment: I guess (!)  that the LongListSelector need the whole list of data. If I knew to do it right, i didn’t need to ask the question, please stop ‘answering’

Comment: It doesn't. So, again, you're doing it wrong, if you think it needs so.

Comment: there is a bug in the Windows Phone Toolkit - Nov 2011 (7.1 SDK) coursing the LongListSelector to group wrong when adding new items in code!